# How can Docker be used efficiently for development?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm experimenting with Docker right now, written an app in Go and I'm building/running it within a container. I am using Docker Compose to stitch it to a database and I'm passing in environment variables.

The issue is that in order to see my changes I must rebuild the Docker image. This take a while because it re-downloads the Go packages each time.

Does this mean Docker is better suited to deployment rather than development?

Comment: How are you getting on with my assistance below, David?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on that for what problem you are using Docker.

Docker is a great tool in order to provide environment virtualization and distribution of the image. This helps in deployment and continuous integration process.

So, it could be useful in development if you are working in a team and needs the same environment to work on.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of misconceptions in your question, which are worth re-examining to get the best out of Docker.

> in order to see my [development] changes I must rebuild the Docker image

One popular approach to development is to have a special launch shell script that does a `docker run` (or `docker-compose up` command) that creates volumes mapped to your development machine's disk. This allows you to make changes in your local machine, and they will be reflected inside your running container immediately.

This way, you don't have to rebuild the machine, and you don't even have to restart it. Of course, when you move to UAT or staging, you will have to rebuild your image, and it won't have these volumes mapped to the host.

> it re-downloads the Go packages each time

This sounds like you are having trouble with your Docker layer caching. Used correctly, your `Dockerfile` should allow you to rebuild your image very quickly from prior builds, unless:

- related files in the project have been changed, or
- a line or a prior line in the `Dockerfile` has been changed

That might be worth addressing in a separate thread.